# Add SQL information to GridView column tooltip

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I have been searching for hours and can not find a solution. i was wondering is there a way to add sql data to a tool tip in ASPX? At the moment i have a GridView which shows information from a database. The final column is a total column, i would like the tool tip to show how the  total was got.

What would be the best way to do this? I am using vb codebehind for this project.

Thanks

Comment: Post your code, both markup and code-behind.

Comment: What do u mean "how the total was got" - do you want to show query/formula there? Is it different for different rows or always sum of all the other columns?

Comment: Total isnt the total of shown column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the cell of your grid view that holds the total value be a server control, like `Label`, and then bind the text to the `ToolTip` property of control like this:

```
<asp:Label id="LabelTotal" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("Formula") %>' />
```

Obviously, this means you need to have a property named "Formula" in the list of objects you are binding to your grid view or a database column named "Formula".